# Too deeply nested (itemize)

Tags: lists, itemize, nesting

So I'm writing this summary for a lecture and I am using `itemize` a lot. The problem I get now is the two times the error (*NB*: `\bi` is my alias for `\begin{itemize}`)

```
     ! LaTeX Error: Too deeply nested.

     See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
     Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
      ...                                              

     l.10 \bi

     ? 
     [21
```

I know that itemize can go four layers deep but in all my document I never go deeper than 2 levels.
To try to find the error I also separated the document and made a single file for each chapter and included them in the main document.
I'm now 99.9% sure that I didn't make any error with nesting but since the error remains I'm a bit desperate.

So I ask you, what I should look for when having that error?
Are there other mistakes that could create this error?

Comment: Hiding LaTeX's environment syntax by making it into a declaration resp. command is not the best idea. Perhaps you forgot `\end{itemize}`.

Comment: Try to provide a Minimal (non-)working example (shortest possible code that generates the error). Without that, we can hardly be helpful in this situation, especially as it is related to some user-defined macros.

Comment: So I found the error. I'm not sure if thats widely known (and I should have known) but here it goes:
At the start of every chapter I wrote a little abstract with the outline of the chapter. I did that with

        \abstract{Here I wrote my stuff}.
Now apparently this opens some sort of nesting and after 4 chapters when I used a 2 level nested itemize I was finally too deeply nested.

When I replaced \abstract{text} with

        \begin{abstract}
        text
        \end{abstract}
It works now.
Trying to get a minimal (non-)working example lead me to the solution, so thanks for helping me :)

Comment: There's no `\abstract` command with an argument, but rather an `abstract` environment, in the standard classes. It's a nuisance that some classes prefer to define an `\abstract` command with an argument, making documents not portable between classes and confusing users.